# Link a TextView value to firebase database ID

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I want to link a `TextView` value to my database item ID. And then get the children that are under my database item in a `TextView`.

When I scan a Barcode with the value 7, I also want the to populate a `TextView` with for example toolName from  the database Item with ID 7.

I've tried and tried, but I don't know how to complete this.

MainActivity:

```
public class UserMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textusername, textworkid, textuserloggedin;

Button btnalltools, qrscan;


DatabaseReference databaseUsers, databaseTools;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser user;

String userID;

String toolid;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_main);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    databaseTools = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("").getReference("Tools");

    textusername = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_textusername);
    textworkid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_textuserworkid);

    qrscan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_qrscantoolactivity);
    qrscan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(UserMainActivity.this);

            intentIntegrator.setPrompt("For flash use volume up key");

            intentIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(true);

            intentIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true);

            intentIntegrator.setCaptureActivity(Capture.class);

            intentIntegrator.initiateScan();


        }
    });

    btnalltools = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_alltoollist);


    btnalltools.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(UserMainActivity.this, ToollistAllActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });



    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("").getReference("Users");
    userID = user.getUid();

    toolid = databaseTools.getKey();

    databaseUsers.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            User userprofile = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

            if (userprofile != null) {

                String user = userprofile.getUserName();
                String userid = userprofile.getUserWorkId();

                textusername.setText(user);
                textworkid.setText(userid);


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    IntentResult intentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (intentResult.getContents() != null){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserMainActivity.this);



        builder.setMessage(intentResult.getContents());



        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.show();


    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I've tried something like this:

```
    IntentResult intentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (intentResult.getContents() != null){

            TextView tv1 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            TextView tv2 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv2);

            tv1.setText(intentResult.getContents());

            databaseTools.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    if (snapshot.hasChildren()){

                        if (tv1.getText().toString().equals(databaseTools)){
                            Tool tools = snapshot.getValue(Tool.class);

                            String tt = tools.getToolID();

                            tv2.setText(tt);

                            
                        }

                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it to work with this:

```
Query gettool = databaseTools.orderByChild("toolID").equalTo(tv1.getText().toString());

        gettool.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){

                        Tool tools = snapshot1.getValue(Tool.class);

                            String tt = tools.getToolName();

                            tv2.setText(tt);


                    }
```